# mongdb: find document between a start-date and end-date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, database

I need to find a document in a collection which has defined a start-date less than the current date and an end-date bigger than the current date

Currently, I create my test document as follows

```
var startDate = new Date(),
    endDate = new Date().setDate(startDate.getDate()+14);
    Tests.insert({ startDate: startDate.getTime(), endDate: endDate.getTime()});
```

On the web I found that it is not very hard to find a document using only one date:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
Tests.find({ created : { $gt :  now - 300, $lt : now + 300}});
```

However, in my case I want to apply the `$gt` on the `startDate` field and the `$lt` to the endDate. How is this done in MongoDB (Note that I'm using Meteor here!)

Comment: See [mongo documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/)

Comment: check, I see it now: `Tests.find({ startDate : { $gt :  now - 300}, endDate: {$lt : now + 300}});`